# What happens if undefined C++ behaviour meets C defined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior

I have a `*.cpp` file that I compile with C++ (not a C compiler). The containing function relies on a cast (see last line) which seems to be defined in C (please correct if I am wrong!), but not in C++ for this special type.

```
[...] C++ code [...]

struct sockaddr_in sa = {0};
int sockfd = ...;
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_port = htons(port);
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa);

[...] C++ code [...]
```

Since I compile this in a C++ file, is this now defined or undefined behaviour? Or would I need to move this into a `*.c` file, to make it defined behaviour?

Comment: The file extension has no meaning; only if you compile it as a C or C++.

Comment: It was used to imply which compiler I used, in this case C++

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178342/compiling-a-c-program-with-gcc , see this. Othewise for sure if your compiler accepts C++ files and compiles them as if they are C files, they are as good as C files and vice-versa. So yes, it completely depends on how your compiler treats the file you supplied it, you will probably have to mention the compiler you use to get concise answers.

Comment: In my example the function is used in a `*.cpp` file, so it is surrounded by C++ code and therefore in C++ context

Comment: I don't see why it would not work in C++. The cast is an object-inheritance-like trick in C.

Comment: The corresponding types are not inherited from each other and have no relationship and that is undefined in C++

Comment: Typically, if the file has `.c` extension, C compiler is invoked automatically.

Comment: Correct, my code is in a C++ file. The question would be, how this will be counted if this is surrounded by C++ code

Comment: I do that trick all the time in C++ code. No idea why it won't work for you. Missing a header somewhere?

Comment: It does work, I am just wondering if that `officially` would be UB or not

Comment: There is no UB in this C++ code. That cast is valid.

Comment: @VTT this is UB in C++ no? (see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#11)

Comment: @DanielStephens This program never tries to dereference pointer. [Cast itself is allowed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#7), dereferencing - only sometimes. If C side correctly casts pointer back to real type then everything should be fine. Problems with casting would may occur if those types had different alignment requirements.

Comment: @user4581301 there are a lot of idioms that were popular long ago that continue to work, even though they are officially undefined behavior.  Because there was so much old code relying on them, the compiler writers try to keep them working even without guarantees.  That doesn't make them good practice.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think these objects are not  pointer-interconvertible, they are not related at all and are not subobjects.

Comment: @VTT - Won't that depend on how exactly the implementation defines them?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, but none of the common implementations define them in such manner.

Comment: It's C++ code, in a C++ source file, compiled as C++. What does C have to do with it? And why do you think this is UB in C++?

Comment: I have misinterpreted the question. This question isn't about whether the code compiles or not, but whether it's strictly legal. I'm getting the smurf out of here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because it's a function call from C times used within C++ context. Context matters ;-) And I expected it to be UB since both types are unrelated

Comment: The historical ancestry of the functions used in your code doesn't appear to be relevant. If your code is C++, your code is C++. Period, full stop. The second point is far more interesting, and I also wonder about this: personally I believe a common prefix makes the cast valid, but I have yet to verify that.

Comment: The cast itself is not undefined behavior [accessing the value would violate strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228315/1708801) bind is part of the implementation.

Comment: You should write code converting from struct sockaddr_in to struct sockaddr; no pointer manipulation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is defined in both C++ and C. It does not violate strict aliasing regulations as it does not dereference the resulting pointer.

Here's the [quote from C++](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#7) (thanks to @interjay and @VTT) that allows this:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.

Here's the [quote from C](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7) (thanks @StoryTeller) that allows this:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type.

These specify that one pointer type can be converted to another pointer type (and then optionally converted back) without consequence.

And here's the [quote from POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html) that allows this specific case:

> The **sockaddr_in** structure is used to store addresses for the Internet address family. Pointers to this type shall be cast by applications to **struct sockaddr *** for use with socket functions.

As this function (`bind`) is part of the C standard library, whatever goes on inside (specifically, dereferencing the type-casted pointer) does not have undefined behavior.

---

To answer the more general question:

C and C++ are two different languages. If something is defined in C but not in C++, it's defined in C but not in C++. No implied compatibility between the two languages will change that. If you want to use code that is well-defined in C but is undefined in C++, you'll have to use a C compiler to compile that code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have a link which refers to "defined in POSIX"?

Comment: What exactly is undefined here?

Comment: @interjay The cast from the `struct sockaddr_in *` to the `struct sockaddr *` violates strict aliasing in C++.

Comment: Casting is allowed. Strict aliasing only prevents dereferencing after the cast, but this isn't done here.

Comment: @interjay Can you back that up with a quote from the standard (either C or C++ is fine)?

Comment: The POSIX reference would be better linked to [clause 2.4](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_04), which says “POSIX.1-2017 is currently specified in terms of the shell command language and ISO C…”

Comment: @JL2210 Here's a reference posted by VTT above: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#7. Can *you* back up the claim that this is undefined?

Comment: The fact that the C++ standard does not define behavior does not prevent a C++ implementation from defining it. I believe GCC has some support for aliasing, via command-line switches, regardless of the C++ standard. So the statement “This must be compiled as C with a POSIX-conforming C implementation for it to be defined” is dubious. It can be compiled with a C++ compiler that supports aliasing.

Comment: @ericpostpischil Wouldn't that be implementation defined behavior that's left up to the compiler.

Comment: @interjay I assume in `bind()` the pointer is dereferenced to be read though.

Comment: Having trouble finding the quote for this being defined in C. Can anyone help?

Comment: @SombreroChicken But `bind` is presumably not implemented in C++. The fact that the calling code is C++ doesn't limit what `bind` can do.

Comment: @JL2210 I'm not convinced it violates strict aliasing; there's a common prefix, no?

Comment: @SombreroChicken: In the C and C++ standards, “implementation defined” means something that **must be** defined by the implementation, not just something that **is** defined by the implementation. If the behavior is “undefined” by the standard, an implementation does not have to do anything with it, but it **may** define it.

Comment: There you go https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7

Comment: @StoryTeller that domain is giving me a certificate error, I am spooked. It can't StoryTell now, mind finding a better host for that quote or writing it down here?

Comment: @SombreroChicken - Really? That's bad. I have way too many answers to fix if that's the case O_O

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks. Added the HTTP version instead, though.

Comment: @StoryTeller I can contact the owner of the page on the #musl IRC to have them update their certificates. It shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @JL2210 Thanks for updating your answer! You mention `as it does not dereference the resulting pointer`. Does that imply dereferencing it on the `C++`-side would make it UB then?

Comment: I am not sure it stops there. Initiated by a recent CppCon talk and referring to your quoted quote  `An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.` the following example introduces two classes who's alignment are not different than the other (that's how the quote continues). But this is UB and visible if Clang and GCC are compared https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/pvBYmS

Comment: @DanielStephens Yes.

Comment: Arguably this is a defect in the POSIX standard -- the second argument to `bind` should be a `const void *`, but `bind` predates the existence of `void` in the C language (and the existence of C++ at all).  They updated it at some point to add the `const`, but never fixed the basic type.

Comment: That explains then why the example in my comment above is UB. hm..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200455/discussion-on-answer-by-jl2210-what-happens-if-undefined-c-behaviour-meets-c-d).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What exactly do you want to be addressed?

Comment: @JL2210 Whether (and why) the cast is valid per strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @DanielStephens Is there anything I can do to improve this answer so you can re-accept it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So... What should I change to address that?

Comment: @JL2210 Say whether it is, and explain why 

Comment: @DanielStephens No problem. Done it myself a couple of times.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is this good? Any other details that it might be a good idea to include?

Comment: I can recommend this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qzMpk-22cc I am still not sure if it validates the answer, or if it is actually saying the opposite :-o C++ is a nightmare.. lol

Comment: Alright, [looks like the rule I was remembering does exist, but only applies to unions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20789178/560648). So it _is_ UB here. Whoops, I use this trick all the time! (Because it's common from C) Probably fine in practice though. You're not wrong to say that the cast itself is fine regardless, but I think the spirit of the question (the pointer _is_ going to be dereferenced!) demands a little exploration of the aliasing problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is slightly different. The resulting pointer is not dereferenced outside of the standard C library, so somehow it's defined.

Comment: Good point! That should also be discussed in the answer (which should provide standard quotes to support it)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My standard-searching capabilities are not up-to-par with the rest of Stack Overflow. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -4):

Calls between C and C++ code all invoke Undefined Behavior, from the point of view of the respective standards, but most platforms specify such things.

In situations where parts of the C or C++ Standard and an implementation's documentation together define or describe an action, but other parts characterize it as Undefined, implementations are allowed to process code in whatever fashion would best serve their customers' needs or--if they are indifferent to customer needs--whatever fashion they see fit.  The fact that the Standard regards such matters as outside their jurisdiction does not imply any judgment as to when and/or how implementations claiming suitability for various purposes should be expected to process them meaningfully, but some compiler maintainers subscribe to a myth that it does.

Comment: First paragraph: _"Calls between C and C++ code all invoke Undefined Behavior"_ Even if there was such a thing as "invoking undefined behaviour" (which there isn't), this still makes no sense.

Comment: Second paragraph: no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think that this answer was a result of my adding the [language-lawyer] tag to the question. I've now thought better of it (the answers tend to be way too literal) and removed it.

Comment: @JL2210 I don't think it was your fault.